# Does it make sense to merge the tag "tax" and "taxes"

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms

Should we merge these tags and create synonyms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement this, cast an upvote here: https://money.stackexchange.com/tags/tax/synonyms

Comment: How many people have enough tag rep in taxes to actually upvote it?

Comment: Am I misreading this? `Users with a total answer score of 5 or more, can vote for tag synonyms.` -- does that mean "answer score of 5 or more *within* the tag", or just anybody with more than 5 points for any answer anywhere? To answer your question there are at least 20 people with >5 rep in **tax** to upvote.

Comment: Within tax is correct.  So you need, 6 of the twenty to go click that button...

Comment: @C. Ross: `automatically approved when they reach a score of 4` -- so only two more clicks?

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and merged the remaining suggestions; don't hesitate to add more tag synonym suggestions as necessary!